# MVC AJAX Post one element from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, jquery

I have a Model that looks a little like this:

```
Public Class MyModel

Public Property ID As Integer
Public Property Name As String
Public Property TypeID As Integer
Public Property Description As String
Public Property MyObjectList As List(Of MyObject)
Public Property MyObjectList2 As List(Of MyObject)
```

My View which is a bit like (simplified/edited for convenience):

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()

@Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) Model.ID)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(Model) Model.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(Function(Model) Model.TypeID)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(Model) Model.Description)

@Html.EditorFor(Function(Model) Model.MyObjectList)
@Html.EditorFor(Function(Model) Model.MyObjectList2)
```

An editor template for MyObject (again heavily edited):

```
<div class="myClass" id="MyObject@(Model.ID)">
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(modelItem) Model.ID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(modelItem) Model.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(modelItem) Model.Description)
```

Via some JavaScript, a user can add more MyObject entries whilst filling in the form.

And in my View a save function that posts back the completed form via AJAX that looks a bit like this:

```
$('#Save').click(function () {        
    $.post("/MyModel/Save", $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
        if (data.Success) {
        }
        else {
        }
    });
});
```

This all works fine.

Now I want another method that will just post back all the information in the fields of just one of the MyObjectLists. Is there anything like the .serialize() method I use on the form that I can limit to all form fields within a certain part of the form? Or do I need to construct a separate JSON object with all the data and pass that back? Or should I just pass the whole thing back and filter out what I need in vb?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery `serialize()` function can act on any jquery object that contains individual form controls.
As you say, usually it is used like `$("form").serialize()` but you could use it over any selection. See the [serialize reference](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

For example, if all the input elements that you want to send have a certain class then you could do something like:

```
  $("form .elementToSend").serialize();
```

You can see it working in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9D6X/)

You will just need to decide a strategy for tagging those fields that you want to send.

Hope it helps!